# кастомная страница в профиле buddypress с планировщиком дел

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, плагин

В Buddypress создал навигацию в меню профиле пользователя, но вот с функционалом проблема.
Есть кастомный пост тип с калорийностью продуктов и блюд. В новой странице в профиле планируется создание диет с выборкой продуктов из вышеописанного типа поста и создать недельный план питания. 
В данном случае есть ли возможность использования встроенных функций wordpress+buddypress или надо писать собственный php с подключением к базе? Если писать, то как это осуществить?